# transaction based in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to get some idea on how to improve (if any) my code in implementing transaction based query in Django.

This is how I understand the ATOMIC_REQUEST I read on django documentation. I have this function view:

```
from django.db import transaction
import sys
@transaction.atomic
def save_progress(request):
   try:
       with atomic.transaction():
           qs = AllProgressModel()
           qs.name = 'level up'
           qs.level = 25
           qs.description = 'Increased 2 level'
           qs.save()
   except:
       print(sys.exc_info())
```

-Am I doing it right? 
-Is the progress will be saved or not if the connection lost occur during saving?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need both decorator `@transaction.atomic` and `with atomic.transaction()`, one is usually enough.

While using `with atomic.transaction()`, catch `IntegrityError` exceptions instead of broadly handling all exceptions at once.

**Edit:** If you're handling exceptions outside the atomic block (like below) then it's a better practice to have an outer atomic wrap as well, for handling rollbacks and other database operations you might need in exception handling part.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction
def save_progress(request):
   try:
       # with atomic.transaction() -> produce error ( typo )
       with transaction.atomic(): 
           ...
           qs.name = 'level up'
           qs.level = 25
           qs.description = 'Increased 2 level'
           qs.save()
   except IntegrityError:
       # You are here if something goes within the transaction, after rollback
       # HANDLE exception
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Only use one? but one of the example on the documentation of django it uses the two.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/ on the Controlling transactions explicitly part

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When handling exceptions like this, you're right, it's better practice. I edited to clarify more why/when you need a second one.